# Running an application with multiple processes in a docker container

Tags: multithreading, docker, docker-compose

Assuming I have a main application that runs by itself multiple sub-applications.
Is it possible to run that main application inside a container?
Currently only the main application starts but the others doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers are started from a single `ENTRYPOINT` but they can of course run multiple binaries. You could, for instance, have a shell script serve as an `ENTRYPOINT` and start call the other binaries from there. Depending on your application it might make sense to put the sub-applications you refer to into their own container.

Comment: that's what i'm trying to avoid. The main application calls the other sub-applications, I think it's a docker thing because outside the docker the application runs perfectly..